# Substitution of $x=\ln y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I must be forgetting a log rule, but I'm reading a solution where $$\frac{x^p}{a^x}$$ equals $$\frac{(\ln y)^p}{y^{\ln a}}$$ after substituting $x = \ln y$ but I can't figure out how that works. I can understand $$a^{\ln y }$$ but then how would I obtain the above denominator? To me, the variables just swapped somehow?

Comment: It's a formula?

Comment: It's a formula that $y^{\ln a} = a^{\ln y}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, amusingly:
$$
\ln \left( a^{\ln(b)} \right)
= \ln(b) \ln(a)
= \ln(a) \ln(b)
= \ln \left( b^{\ln(a)} \right)
$$
so, raising both sides to the power of $e$,
$$
a^{\ln(b)} = b^{\ln(a)}
$$
provided that $a,b > 0$.

Comment: Based upon my question, it's clear I've never seen that identity before so this is very helpful (and I'd almost say surprising, as in almost too good to be true (though I suppose it's due to restrictions on the variables))

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking why $a^{\ln y} = y^{\ln a}$. It's true that it's a formula you can remember, but you can also see it by letting $b = a^{\ln y}$. If I take the logarithm of both sides, I can see that:
$$\ln b = \ln (a^{\ln y}) = \ln y \ln a = \ln (y^{\ln a}),$$
and from here you can see that $b = y^{\ln a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see that for $a, b \gt 0, a^{ \ln b}= b^{\ln a}$, which is completely equivalent to the analyses you've seen in other answers, is to remember that $a=e^{\ln a}$, so for any $t \in \Bbb R, a^t=(e^{\ln a})^t=e^{t \ln a}$.  Thus,

$$a^{\ln b}=e^{\ln a \cdot \ln b}= e^{\ln b \cdot \ln a}=b^{\ln a}.$$